# Data missing while scraping website

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to scrap a website (Please refer to urls in the code). 
From the website ,i am trying to scrap all the information and transfer the data to json file.

```
scrapy shell http://www.narakkalkuries.com/intimation.html
```

To extract the information from website

```
response.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid"]/tr/td[1]//text()').re(r'[0-9,-/]+|[0-9]+')
```

I am able to retrieve most of the information from the website.

**Concern:**
Able to scrap data under "Intimation",expect'Intimation For  September 2017' not able to scrap information under this tab.

**Finding:**

For 'Intimation For  September 2017', the value is stored in the span tag

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[32]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/p/b/span
```

For the remaining month the values are stored in the font tag

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[35]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/p/b/span/font
```

How to extract information for "Intimation For  September 2017" ?

Answer (score 1):

You tables use different `@class` (`MsoTableGrid` and `MsoNormalTable`) so you need some way to process all of them:

```
for table in response.xpath('//table[@width="519"]'):
    for row in table.xpath('./tr[position() > 1]'):
        for cell in row.xpath('./td'):
            #you can stringify value
            cell_value = cell.xpath('string(.)').extract_first()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helping me in pointing out that it's different tables "MsoTableGrid" and "MsoNormalTable' . I made modification to the exist Xpath "response.xpath('//table[@class="MsoTableGrid" or @class= "MsoNormalTable"]/tr/td[1]//text()').re(r'[0-9,-/]+|[0-9]')" Now i am able to retrieve the values for the required value